# Laravel ErrorException Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a contact form and when I press the post, I register, but it gives the following error.

```
ErrorException
Array to string conversion
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $table = ['contact'];
}
```

Controller

```
 public function contactpost(Request $request) {
        $contact = new Contact;
        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->topic = $request->topic;
        $contact->message = $request->message;
        $contact->save();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Usually, such an error message contains the exact line and the file triggering the error

Comment: When I press a form on my contact page, I want to register the response I received via post to the database, but there is a problem.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by edting it. Additionally, add your debugging attempts and the **full and exact** error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the model you set the `protected $table = ['contact'];` to a array, this should be a string like so:

`protected $table = 'contact';`

Please read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

And **if** you use the Laravel conventions then there is no need to set the `$table` yourself as Laravel will guess the name based of the Model name.